# Prevent Users from Sending OAuth Token to Other Users

Tags: security, oauth

Let's say a user is accessing a particular resource at:

```
http://myapp/resource/id?access_token=123
```

and his colleague asks him what the link to that particular resource is. The user sends his link which INCLUDES THE TOKEN! Now the colleague accesses the link as the other user! Is there a way to prevent this?

The only thing I could think of is for the server to only accept POST requests, that way the client doesn't need to put the token in the link. Are there other ways to do this?

A more general question is, without using session variables, how can the server know if the user sending the request with the access token know if it's the same user as the one who authenticated the client?

Comment: How did you end up with an access token in the URL in the first place? What happened to your cookies?

Comment: Are cookies the best way to store tokens. By the way, my tokens only last 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes, cookies are the usual way to store access credentials. They don't show up in URLs and can be made invisible to JavaScript, so they're inherently less likely to accidentally end up somewhere they shouldn't.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll have to do that. I'm new to OAuth and none of these tutorials mention cookies. Thanks!

Comment: Unless they have the client id, secret, and the redirect URI to match the access_token they really cant do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store access tokens in URLs. Cookies are the usual way to store access credentials. They don't show up in URLs and can be made invisible to JavaScript, so they're inherently less likely to accidentally end up somewhere they shouldn't.